# MotionEvent.getY() returning zero far above the visible screen

Tags: android, android-studio

Hello,

I have a TextureView at the top of my layout.  For this example it is in portrait orientation.  The device for testing is a Galaxy Note 2 (
4.1.2 ).  For this example I need for you to distinguish between the face of the device ( where the Samsung logo and camera is ) and the display ( visible pixels ).

When I receive touch events in the TextureView I use MotionEvent.getY() to retrieve the Y component of the touch location.  I would hope that .getY() would return zero at the top of the view.  This does not seem to be the case. .getY() returns close to zero when I am touching the very top of the device ( above the Samsung logo ).  At the border of the display I receive a .getY() value of approximately 50 ( I believe it should be zero ).  I am using a theme for NoTitleBar Fullscreen if that has any effect.  I have used several methods to try to get the offset of the view  ( .getTop, getLocationInWindow, etc... ).  They all return zero for x and y.  I assume this will be varied for different devices ( hardcoding a value will not work ).

This is boggling my mind.  Any ideas?

darf

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [View.getLocationOnScreen()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLocationOnScreen(int[]))?

Comment: Yes.  Returns 0,0.  I could understand it if the locations off the top of the display returned negative values.  But this doesn't make any sense.